# Error: One Nix Package Trying to Paste a File into Another Nix Package (self.NixOS) submitted

Tags: nix

### 1 Context

I am trying to build nix expressions for two packages:

1. `OSVR-Core`
2. `OSVR-Vive`

I have successfully written (1); however, I am having a problem with (2). This is partially because in order to build (2), you need (1) as a dependency. But here's the problem: (2) tries to paste a file into (1).

### 2 Error Message

Here is the error message I'm getting when trying to build (2):

```
-- Installing: /nix/store/9y6p1npy94sbpb39l0rd8rgdhbknll6r-OSVR-Core/lib/osvr-plugins-0/com_osvr_Vive.so
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:50 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot copy file
  "/tmp/nix-build-OSVR-Core.drv-0/OSVR-Vive-e0ebcdb/build/nix/store/9y6p1npy94sbpb39l0rd8rgdhbknll6r-OSV
R-Core/lib/osvr-plugins-0/com_osvr_Vive.so"                                                            
  to
  "/nix/store/9y6p1npy94sbpb39l0rd8rgdhbknll6r-OSVR-Core/lib/osvr-plugins-0/com_osvr_Vive.so".


make: *** [Makefile:74: install] Error 1
builder for ‘/nix/store/cj1yzm9x1pdyzwd76dh7xn1vq6zvcnq2-OSVR-Core.drv’ failed with exit code 2
```

As you can see, `OSVR-Vive` tries to paste a file into `/nix/store/*-OSVR-Core/lib/osvr-plugins-0`, and fails.

### 3 Nix Expressions (in case relevant)

**OSVR-Core.nix**

```
{ pkgs, stdenv, fetchgit, cmake, jsoncpp, opencv, python27, libusb1, boost }:

stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "OSVR-Core";
  buildInputs = with pkgs; [ cmake
                            jsoncpp
                            opencv
                            python27
                            libusb1
                            boost
                            (callPackage ./libfunctionality.nix { })
                            ];
  src = fetchgit {
    url       = "https://github.com/OSVR/OSVR-Core.git";
    rev       = "95655d3174851670b85e9be8e8620ba28f9872f4";
    sha256    = "16sbfv4fxcvxqhm81in8lkvjpfbiz312kh7pm4vipj7dja1fchy8";
    deepClone = true; # git clone --recursive
  };
}
```

**OSVR-Vive.nix**

```
{ pkgs, stdenv, fetchgit, cmake, eigen3_3, boost, jsoncpp }:

stdenv.mkDerivation {
  name = "OSVR-Vive";
  buildInputs = with pkgs; [ cmake
                            (callPackage ./libfunctionality.nix { })
                            (callPackage ./OSVR-Core.nix { })
                            eigen3_3
                            boost
                            jsoncpp
                            ];
  src = fetchgit {
    url    = "https://github.com/OSVR/OSVR-Vive.git";
    rev    = "e0ebcdbe2d065448fcebacc2828712a946695004";
    #sha256 = "1cf90x2ddqgylh98ssigr5c86l8psa3q512rl933kpz93n2can5g";
    sha256 = "1d10gp7xalqdclskxc804fp56gz3k1sqzzqbdm3y54iwshmahwfw";
    deepClone = true; # git clone --recursive
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your post, it looks like OSVR-Core is some kind of software that accepts plugins, and OSVR-Vive is a plugin for OSVR-Core.  Plugins are meant to be stored as shared objects in the `lib/osvr-plugins-0` directory wherever OSVR-Core is installed.

That plan would work fine on a normal Linux system where the filesystem is a free-for-all and programs just install themselves wherever they want to, but that is not how Nix behaves.

First of all, you should make and apply a patch to `OSVR-Vive` so that it installs its plugin to somewhere in its own Nix store output.

Next, you should change OSVR-Core so that it knows how to find such plugins at runtime.  I would suggest there should be an environment variable called OSVR_PLUGIN_PATH and that OSVR-Core should search all the directories listed in that variable for plugins.  That mechanism might already exist; you can check the documentation and source code of OSVR-Core to see if it does.

Another plan would be to build `OSVR-Core` and `OSVR-Vive` in the same derivation so they can both write files to the same `lib` directory.  That does not sound ideal in general, but you could probably get it to work without doing any patching.

### How to patch software in Nix

To make a patch, what should do is extract two copies of the software's source code in one directory, and name one of them with a suffix that is something like "-orig".  Then modify the other copy.  Then run:

```
diff -ur mysoftware-orig mysoftware > mypatch.patch
```

Then you can include that in your Nix derivation.  If you are using the standard nixpkgs setup for building, I think you just write something like:

```
patches = [ ./mypatch.patch; ];
```

Anyway, you can look in the nixpkgs repository for lots of examples of how to patch software.